# php page which accepts input after sanitizing the values

Tags: php, javascript

I have a page which I modified to accept input from the user and then it will sanitize the input values and then compare the password. It will then re-route to another page. My only concern is the XSS and script insertion in the input values. Heres my Code:

```
<?php
/**
 * ****************************************************************************
 * Micro Protector
 * 
 * Version: 1.0
 * Release date: 2007-09-10
 * 
 * USAGE:
 *   Define your requested password below and inset the following code
 *   at the beginning of your page:
 *   <?php require_once("microProtector.php"); ?>
 * 
 *   See the attached example.php.
 * 
 ******************************************************************************/


$Password = 'testpass'; // Set your password here



/******************************************************************************/
   if (isset($_POST['submit_pwd'])){

// Clean up the input values 
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {  
    $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]); 

    $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key])); 
}

      $pass = isset($_POST['passwd']) ? $_POST['passwd'] : '';

      if ($pass != $Password) {
         showForm("Wrong password");
         exit();     
      }
   } else {
      showForm();
      exit();
   }

function showForm($error="LOGIN"){
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
   <title>IMC - Authentication</title>
   <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<Script>
<!--
function capitalize(form) {
    value = form.value;
    newValue = '';
    value = value.split(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        newValue += value[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() +
        value[i].substring(1,value[i].length) + '';
    }
newValue = newValue.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
form.value = newValue;
}
-->
</Script>
</head>
<body>
<center><a href="http://www.test.com"><img src="http://www.test.com/theImages/topLogo.png" border=0 /></a></center>
<br><br><br>
    <div id="main">
      <div class="caption"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
      <div id="icon">&nbsp;</div>
      <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="pwd">
    Your Name:
        <table>
          <tr><td><input class="text" name="name" onBlur="capitalize(this);" maxlength=12 type="text" /></td></tr>
        </table> 
        Password:
        <table>
          <tr><td><input class="text" name="passwd" maxlength=8 type="password" /></td></tr>
          <tr><td align="center"><br/>
             <input class="text" type="submit" name="submit_pwd" value="Login" />
          </td></tr>
        </table>  
      </form>
   </div>
</body>
</html>

<?php   
}
?>
```

Question: Is the above php page secure enough to ensure user won't be able to insert any  tag or perform a XSS attack?

**EDIT**: 
$_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]); **and** $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key])); are ok to be included together?

Comment: Are you sure you know what XSS is? You don't seem to be outputting *any* user input into the page. So there's no chance to inject anything. As such: yes, it's safe. But no, the escaping you're doing is pointless.

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: This question also belongs more on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It takes the Name, the user entered and inserts it into the re routed page. I updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erm... You aren't outputting the user-supplied data in any way, so it is completely injection-proof.

Note that your "escaping" is destructive. If my password were `\<I am awesome!>\` then I would never be able to log in.

Comment: <?php echo $name ?>! is outputted on the re routed page. Well I have the password set on the top of the page and the users who will access this page already knows the password. Escaping was done to prevent entering <> in the NAME field. But since i am using stripslashes and strip tags in PHP, can i remove the "Escaping" line?

Comment: As long as you are only sending `echo $name` to the person who posted it, and not saving it anywhere to show to everyone, then any injection would be self-destructive and would not affect you, your server, or your other users.

Comment: ok Thank you. That's all i needed to know. I can now feel safe in uploading it to my server. Thanks again!